# VS2017 - how to remove per-class warnings about dependency validation

Tags: c#, visual-studio

This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41913385/visual-studio-2017-disable-dependency-validation)

I have disabled the options for dependency validation warnings in the Tools -> Options -> Dependency Validation  section, and I do not get the yellow warning bar at the top of the screen, however I am getting the following warning on every single class in my solution:

```
warning DV2002: Class 'NavigationBarView' is not mapped to any Dependency Validation diagram
```

Additionally, every class name in the solution has the green squiggle underline which states the same, but there are no offered fixes.

This occurred after we branched our solution in TFS, and it's only occurring on the new branch, but nobody else on the team knows how it was disabled on previous branches.

We do not wish to use dependency validation, how can I remove this?  So far in the official docs I've only found how to disable the yellow bar warning.

Edit: Forgot to mention that I know how to suppress compiler warnings at the project level, but none of the previous branches have this warning in the build properties nor any pragma that I can find, which is why I am curious if there's something configurable at the solution level to disable this check.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio 2017 and Visual Studio 2019, you can create a "Code Analysis Rule Set" that applies Solution Wide.  I was able to eliminate 1300+ new warnings by turning off DV2002.  I added the new file in the root of our source tree as a sibling to the sln file.  It worked solution-wide.

The DV2002 warnings arrived in volume for us when we upgraded from VS2017 to VS2019.

[VS2017 - Create a new rule set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/how-to-create-a-custom-rule-set?view=vs-2017)

[VS2019 - Create a new rule set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/how-to-create-a-custom-rule-set?view=vs-2019#create-a-new-rule-set)

[image: New | File]

[image: Code Analysis Rule Set]

[image: Rule Set Editor]

Answer (score 0):

From Build tab in Project Properties. Type the warning ID (`DV2002` in this case) in Suppress Warnings text box in similar way to the following example:

[image: Supress Warnings]

Comment: This was going to be our fallback option.  Is there a solution-level suppression somewhere?  This isn't set on any projects in the previous branches where we aren't getting the warning, which leads me to believe there's a higher level option we are missing somewhere.

Comment: Not as I'm aware of. Solutions have little control over compilation and work mostly as "grouping" of projects.